# Laravel vue js npm run watch works only one time

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vuejs2

I'm developing laravel vue project.And i am using homestead for development. when i run

`npm run watch`

it only executes once and not executing when i do changes on my code and refresh the browser.

I tried `--watch--poll` also. but works only once.
[image]
Is there any commands that i can use to automatically compile the code each time when i make changes to the code or any solutions for this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. need to run it outside the homestead environment.